# Based on category ids I want to include different headers

Tags: wordpress, categories

Based on category ids I want to include different headers.

Eg:

If array of category id - `1,2,3` include `header1.php`

elseif array of category id - `4,5,6` include `header2.php`

I just wrote the basic flow on how I want it.

What should be the actual code go and where should I put it.

The code which I've used is

```
<?php

// Get the current user level from WP

$user = wp_get_current_user();

// Get user levels from WishlistMembers

$levels = WLMAPI::GetUserLevels($user->ID);

// Then run the check for the level you want like this:

if(in_array('Free', $levels) && in_array('Print', $levels) && in_array('Web', $levels) && (is_category(array(78, 'artilces-web', 'Articles')) || is_category(array(82, 'book-review-web', 'Book Review')) || is_category(array(87, 'books-at-glance-web', 'Books at Glance')) )){

 // Display web subscriber header

   include("header3.php");

}

elseif(in_array('Free', $levels) && in_array('Print', $levels)){

 // Display print subscriber header

   include("header2.php");

}

elseif (in_array('Free', $levels) && in_array('Web', $levels) && (is_category(array(78, 'artilces-web', 'Articles')) || is_category(array(82, 'book-review-web', 'Book Review')) || is_category(array(87, 'books-at-glance-web', 'Books at Glance')) )){

   //  Display web subscriber header

   include("header3.php");

}

elseif (in_array('Print', $levels) && in_array('Web', $levels) && (is_category(array(78, 'artilces-web', 'Articles')) || is_category(array(82, 'book-review-web', 'Book Review')) || is_category(array(87, 'books-at-glance-web', 'Books at Glance')) )){

   //  Display web subscriber header

   include("header3.php");

}

elseif(in_array('Free', $levels)){

  // Display free subscriber header

  include("header1.php");

}

elseif (in_array('Print', $levels)){

   // Display print subscriber header

   include("header2.php");

}

elseif (in_array('Web', $levels) && (is_category(array(78, 'artilces-web', 'Articles')) || is_category(array(82, 'book-review-web', 'Book Review')) || is_category(array(87, 'books-at-glance-web', 'Books at Glance')) )){

   // Display web subscriber header

   include("header3.php");

}

else {

    include("header.php");

}

?>
```

Comment: Have you done any efforts so far ? If you tried anything than post the same here.

Comment: Please try first, though if you have no clue, there will most likely be a plugin for that.

Comment: @NigelAngel - No need of any plugin it can just done by some simple conditions.

Comment: i think you might use `get_template_part()` for including headers...

Comment: @Rikesh I know this, but OP may have great difficultly with coding. They've shown no code and haven't indicated that they have the slightest clue about how to go about it. In this case a plugin may be more suitable.

Comment: @Rikesh - I've done some coding but don't know this did not work. Am using Wishlist membership plugin and based on the 3 levels had created 3 headers. Now that I created categories, and when I click any of the category its including the default header and not either of the 3 headers created.

Comment: I've added the code which am using, but this did not work. Am getting the users as based on levels (free, print and web). When a user logs in, based on the level, respective header will be included.  But now the problem is, I've created categories for web and print. When a post is clicked in category it includes default header and not the print or the web header. Please assist where am I wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:-

```
if( in_category( array(1,2,3) ) )
{
    //Call Here header1.php
    get_template_part( 'header1');
}
elseif( in_category( array(4,5,6) ) )
{
    //Call Here header2.php
    get_template_part( 'header2');
} else {
    get_header();
}
```

Hope this will help you..